# safari browser shows lines around div-- issue/bug

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

My website link is "http://orangecountyclassiccars.com/"
and its in PHP. When user clicks on comment button near to FBlike button, A Facebook comment-box appears. It perfect in all browsers but when open in apple/Mac it shows lines behind Facebook comment-box.

Here is attached Screenshot.

[image]

Thank You

Comment: Comments box doesn't even open in Safari 5.1.7 on W7. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: I am using same version of safari 5.1.7 its opening. Its strange... Any help please?

Comment: Must be MAC OS specific then